# Why injecting EntityManagerInterface return me a Cannot serialize PhpFilesAdapter error

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a problem that I've never encountered before even if I've done this on an other project. I tried to inject an EntityManagerInterface into my User entity (in order to fetch something in a configuration database). So I've used the @PostLoad technic.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface $em */
    private $em;
    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     * @ORM\PostPersist
     */
    public function fetchEntityManager(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->setEntityManager($args->getEntityManager());
    }

    public function setEntityManager($em) {
        $this->em=$em;
    }
}
```

I've already done this in an other project but not in the user entity and it worked just fine. But now I get this error:

> Cannot serialize Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\PhpFilesAdapter

I think that creating a sort of utility class that could prevent me from injecting the entityManagerInterface in my entity will help me but I don't know what type of class should I use, a Service maybe ?

Comment: first of all ... ewww, entities should not have access to the entity manager. but regarding your problem: some security parts will serialize the user object for the session, and it will try to serialize everything in the user object, unless you define a serialize/unserialize function, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session since the session stuff probably somewhere references the caching stuff that can't be serialized, you should adapt serialization.

Comment: I would like to not use entitymanager in my entity but I don’t know how to access my data without

Comment: As @Jakumi said the user entity is being serialized. On each Request symfony will query the user object to make sure the logged in user is the same between requests. Maybe create a Service that implement \Serializable, lets say UserService and inject the EntityManagerInterface there.

Comment: @MikeDevresse it really depends on what you want to achieve, but I can assure you, that the EntityManager should not be necessary in an entity, since the entity should only care about its own integrity, everything beyond that should be managed by some service or repository.

Comment: I want in the user entity to be able to get a rank based on a calculation and on the rank configuration that I get from the database. I just need the rank config array from the database.

Comment: so your user repository should possibly provide an additional function for fetching a user *with* the rank, the rank calculation *may* be done in the repository or a specific service and then set via a setter on the entity. if you want to get really fancy, you could also use a proxy object, that does some if not all of this. However, this goes way beyond the scope of your question though.

Comment: I'll try but it seems a lot for a simple thing. I could do it if I enter my configuration in brut code but I need it to be variable. I'll test it and come back when I have a result ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not entirely unrelated to your question: injecting an entity manager into an entity indicates a bad design and is not intended in symfony/doctrine's orm.

what is causing your problem is, that the [user is serialized by symfony's session management](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session) and when it tries to serialize a sufficiently complex object/service, it'll probably fail to do so. It is recommended to implement the Serializable interface to only serialize stuff that is actually needed (see same link). Which will solve this and other possible problems you might get. It also reduces the size of the session, which might get larger the bigger your application grows and attaches to the user object. Since the user object is loaded on every request anyway, serializing anything more than the mentioned properties (same link again) is simply wasteful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help that was it, I did the things that you told me in the other comment to do the calculation that I need in the repository, plus I added a service so I can access it easily in twig.

Answer (score 0):

I use Symfony 5.3.9 and for me worked, after thousand of hours of try, to call "composer update"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).